# Fix maximised 2D Panel window buttons

Tags: 12.04, themes, unity-2d, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any GTK3 themes that work properly in Unity-2D? All that I've tried have “button glitches”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122812/are-there-any-gtk3-themes-that-work-properly-in-unity-2d-all-that-ive-tried-ha)

I'm using the Unity 2D Panel and when I maximise a window, I notice the buttons on the panel aren't the same as the theme. When I use Ambiance, the buttons are fixed, so what do I have to do in order to fix this? If it's any help, I'm using the Zukitwo theme with different window buttons

[image]